# What is this icon depicting a phone and Wi-Fi together?

Tags: notification-icons, nokia-6

After I factory reset my Nokia 6, this icon appeared. I've never seen it before. What is this icon in the highlighted part? [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is WiFi calling icon or VoWiFi. Disabling that WiFi settings removed the icon as confirmed by OP

It is used for making voice calls over WiFi, similar to Volte ( more so when signal connectivity is poor). On some phones, it is slightly different with the solid triangle replaced by traditional WiFi icon as shown [here](http://lowdown.carphonewarehouse.com/how-to/what-do-the-symbols-on-my-screen-mean/29341/)

[image]