# Which circumstances allows 2 phone icons to be displayed on the notification bar?

Tags: notification-icons, android-12, motorola

I'm using Motorola Moto G50 on Android 12. I noticed that there are 2 phone icons on the notification bar, one on the left and the other beside the clock icon on the right.

[image]

How come? Could this be the case of a forwarding call? or something related to that kind of service?

Comment: Hello. The icon on the right side shows that Wifi calling is enabled. See https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/188407/what-is-this-icon-depicting-a-phone-and-wi-fi-together

Comment: thanks for the response sir, but I was wondering WHY the wificall icon is SIMULTANEOUSLY being displayed with regular, every example img I've saw, only 1 were displayed not BOTH at the same time. should the regular one be a call on "wait' or so?

Comment: On my Samsung note 20, the wifi call is displayed if it's enabled and there is wifi available.   The phone icons is displayed only during a call.

Comment: bro, actually, I guess I was right, the wifi-call icon is in fact displaying cuz that SS was taken during a call, but as I was looking the moto g50 manual, the first one indicates that calls are cxurrently being diverted, I don't think I'm wrong bout this.
https://prnt.sc/edEudA8qfpkE
https://deviceguides.vodafone.co.uk/motorola/moto-g50-android-11-0/getting-started/list-of-screen-icons/

Comment: @Kalikaze looks like call divert (and missed calls) icon has an additional arrow, not a plain phone icon.